# Eliminate duplicate code that builds similar copies of the same object

Tags: java, duplication

I have two classes that both build an object, and at the moment there is duplicate code in both these classes, e.g this code exists in class 1:

```
new Object("a", "b", "c");
```

Only one of the arguments to the constructor varies. So this code exists in class 2:

```
new Object("x", "b", "c");
```

Is there any pattern to get rid of this code duplication?

Comment: Could you give some more details

Answer (score 5):

You can add a constructor to the class.

```
class MyObject {
    MyObject(String a) {
       this(a, "b", "c");
    }

    MyObject(String a, String b, String c) {
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, also it's a good idea to think of object factories or static methods with a meaningful name to convey the use case of object creation.

Answer (score 1):

@Peter Lawrey's solution is good. 
One question though, why do you pass constant arguments to the object constructor if they do not change?
If you remove those constant parameters, you end up with:

```
public MyObject(String a){
   this.a = a;
   this.b = "b";
   this.c = "c";
}
```